# Ghost theme display more than 5 posts per page

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost

How can I display more than 5 posts in the loop on the homepage of a theme?

I have the standard loop:

```
{{#foreach posts}}
  <h2 class="post-title">{{{title}}}</h2>
{{/foreach}}
```

I have 7 posts in total, but can only display 5 per page, it seems to forcibly paginate at 5 posts.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: Hi, @Nicekiwi! Could you maybe remove the check mark from my answer because it isn’t the right one anymore and I would like to remove, which is only possible when it isn’t tagged as the accepted answer anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Ghost is showing only 5 posts per page. You can change that in the blog settings under **general**, where you can upload your blog icon and cover, too.

**UPDATE: This answer is deprecated!**

But it can’t be removed because it was tagged as the accepted answer !

Comment: With new versions of ghost, this answer is outdated.

Answer (score 19):

Since Ghost v1.0, you can change this now by editing the theme's `package.json` under `config`.  The default Casper theme is probably a good place to look for reference:

```
"config": {
  "posts_per_page": 25
}
```

Comment: [To reference the doc](https://themes.ghost.org/docs/packagejson#section--config-posts_per_page-)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue for my blog.

There are 2 ways you can go about it.

**1) Use *[limit](https://ghost.org/docs/api/v2/handlebars-themes/helpers/foreach/#the-limit-attribute)***

```
{{#foreach posts limit="7"}}
 <h2 class="post-title">{{{title}}}</h2>
{{/foreach}}
```

2) Edit the ***[posts_per_page](https://ghost.org/faq/posts-per-page/)*** variable in packaga.json (This will apply to all posts)

```
//package.json

"config": { "posts_per_page": 7 }
```